# Use createSelector (or any memoized selector) with hooks without mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reselect

I want to create a memoized selector which will update automatically when the state in the redux store changes.

I read about Reselect's `createSelector` here:

https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data

I see that mapStateToProps is being used to connect the selector to the store.. I'm currently using redux with hooks only (`useDispatch` and `useSelector`) without using `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)`.

Is there a way to use `createSelector` but still without using `connect`? If not, is there maybe another way to create a memoized selector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are *nearly* equivalent. `useSelector` takes a pure function that when invoked is passed the entire redux store (i.e. state). Unlike Reselect's selectors however, they do not have the ability to receive passed props (other than through closure or currying). Save for a few edge cases most of your standard Reselect state selectors can be used with react-redux's useSelector hook.

Reselect selectors are memoizing selectors, so [here](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors) is the section for working with them.

[useSelector redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector)